# Generate CSV from Java object and move to Azure Storage without intermediate location

Tags: java, csv, azure, storage, csv-write-stream

Is it possible to create a file like CSV from Java object and move them to Azure Storage without using temporary location?

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far (show us some code) and what are the issues you're running into.

Comment: @GauravMantri The current system creates CSV files out of Java Objects and stores them in a path like "C:\temp". I read the CSV files from here and move them to Azure Storage. What I want to do now is to eliminate the temp location part and serialize the Java Objects to directly move them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description , it seems that you want to upload a CSV file without taking up your local space. So, I suggest you use stream to upload CSV files to Azure File Storage.

Please refer to the sample code as below ：

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFile;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFileClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFileDirectory;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFileShare;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.StringBufferInputStream;

public class UploadCSV {

    // Configure the connection-string with your values
    public static final String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
                    "AccountName=<storage account name>;" +
                    "AccountKey=<storage key>";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the Azure Files client.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

            StorageCredentials sc = fileClient.getCredentials();

            // Get a reference to the file share
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("test");

            //Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

            //Get a reference to the file you want to download
            CloudFile file = rootDir.getFileReference("test.csv");

            file.upload( new StringBufferInputStream("aaa"),"aaa".length());

            System.out.println("upload success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I upload the file into the account successfully.

[image]

You could also refer to the threads:

1.[Can I upload a stream to Azure blob storage without specifying its length upfront?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618545/can-i-upload-a-stream-to-azure-blob-storage-without-specifying-its-length-upfron/24621538#24621538)

2.[Upload blob in Azure using BlobOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748705/upload-blob-in-azure-using-bloboutputstream)

Hope it helps you.